# How does this function parse strings? I want to understand the theory

Tags: c, string, gcc, glibc

In this code I do not quite understand the lines
`s += strspn (s, delim);`
and
`end = s + strcspn (s, delim);`
As far as I know strspn returns the index of first occurrence of a delimiter in string.
Therefore if `s` is the string, then the `delimiter` is at index `strcspn (s, delim)-1`.
So, the command `s += strspn (s, delim)` would move the string pointer to the index after the delimiter.
Which means if I have a string `s = "Abc,dsf.eerr"` and `delim = " ,.\n"` and then if I execute this line, `s += strspn (s, delim);` then does that mean *s = 'd'?
What is the significance of this line `end = s + strcspn (s, delim);`.
I need to implement strtok where the delimiter is not deleted but returned as a parameter. I just need to understand how this code works to do so. This might be a very basic question but still thanks for your help.

```
char *
__strtok_r (char *s, const char *delim, char **save_ptr)
{
  char *end;
  if (s == NULL)
    s = *save_ptr;
  if (*s == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = s;
      return NULL;
    }
  /* Scan leading delimiters.  */
  s += strspn (s, delim);
  if (*s == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = s;
      return NULL;
    }
  /* Find the end of the token.  */
  end = s + strcspn (s, delim);
  if (*end == '\0')
    {
      *save_ptr = end;
      return s;
    }
  /* Terminate the token and make *SAVE_PTR point past it.  */
  *end = '\0';
  *save_ptr = end + 1;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: You may use debugger to run it step by step, checking what each line is doing

Comment: From the man page: `strspn` returns the index of the first character in `s` which is **not** in the `delim` string. So the second sentence (*"As far as I know strspn returns the index of first occurrence of a delimiter in string."*) is not correct. Perhaps you meant `strcspn` instead of `strspn` in that sentence.

Comment: So, tell me why we use strspn for s and then strcspn for end?

Comment: For example, if the delim is just a space character, then `strspn` will return the index of the first character that isn't a space character. That is, it finds the beginning of a token. Then `strcspn` finds the index of the first character that *is* a space character. That is, it finds the first character *after* the token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine it like this:

```
char *str = ",.,.,.DEF,.,.,.GAH";
char *s = str;
char *delim = ",.";
```

Now, you want to get to field `DEF`. So what you do:

To find the start of the field, you have to advance as long as there are delimiters:

- `s += strspn(s, delim)`
- `strspn(s, delim) = strlen(",.,.,.") = 6`
- So `*s = D`

To find the end of the field from there, you have to advance as long as there are no delimiters:

- `end = s + strcspn(s, delim)`
- `strcspn(s, delim) = strlen("DEF") = 3`
- So: `*end = ','`

> Which means if I have a string s = "Abc,dsf.eerr" and delim = " ,.\n" and then if I execute this line, s += strspn (s, delim); then does that mean *s = 'd'?

No, `strspn("Abc,dsf.eerr", " ,.\n") = 0`. `A` is not in `" ,.\n"`.

> What is the significance of this line end = s + strcspn (s, delim);

To find the end of the field, which we will be starting from on the next cycle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain it.